# Should a question about a software release date be closed when it is released?

Tags: support, close-reasons

I have seen a few questions which ask when the next version of a some software will be released.  Should a question about a software release date be closed when the software is released?

Examples:

- [When does Windows 7 release for
  MSDN?](https://superuser.com/questions/1318/when-does-windows-7-release-for-msdn)
- [Delphi 2010… when will we
  see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127681/delphi-2010-when-will-we-see-it)

Comment: Why ask such questions in the first place? When would an answer be acceptable?

Comment: I don't mind people asking such question prior to the release and it may bring more people to the sites.  Choosing when to accept an answer is for the asker to decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will even go as far as deleting it. Closed questions still are in the system, but this kind of questions clearly has a expiry date. Obviously for a short period it could teach others that it already had been released, but after a certain time, there is no value in them any longer.

So I would flag them for moderator attention with "delete as no longer relevant".

Comment: I agree, these sorts of questions are like milk -- after the expiration date, they've "gone bad" and should be deleted.

Comment: Your right.  I think they should be closed after they expire and then deleted after a few weeks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I think Close as "no longer relevant" seems the right option here.

Answer (score 1):

As a person responsible for asking question about Delphi 2010 I voted today for closing, using “no longer relevant". This question was both about release date of Delphi 2010 and about 64bit compiler for Delphi.  The part about Delphi 2010 is no longer relevant, but part about 64bit is still important. So I think this question should be closed (unfortunately I cannot close it by myself), but I think I would not delete it, since info about 64 bit compiling is still relevant.

Comment: As I told you in a comment to the question: it is still very valid,as the 64bit part has not been delivered with Delphi 2010. Edit the title, stressing the 64bit part. And add a sentence to the question that it originally asked about the release date of 2010 to explain some of the answers.

Comment: @Ralph Rickenbach - You are right. I edited it slightly.

Comment: @smok1 - You could ask another question about when 64 bit support will be available for Delphi.

Comment: @stukelly - I will ask such question probably in a near future.